# Dynamic change label and placeholder depends on loaded html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I am using jquery with laravel on backend. I have searchbar that loaded on two php blades. I want placeholder and label to dynamic change depends on loaded php blade file. This is how it looks right now, it only display first label and placeholder and even in id do not exist in blade it shows first label and placeholder.

**HTML/BLADE.PHP**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="show-hide-section">
            <button class="btn btn-success show-hide-search-bar">Pokaż wyszukiwarkę</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="searcher-section" style="display: none">
                <div class="show-hide-searcher">
                    <div class="input-section">

                        <div class="label-input-searcher">
                            <label for="" class="searcher-label" id="label-searchbar"></label>

                            <input type="text" placeholder="" class="searcher-input form-control" id="input-searchbar" />
                            <div class="null-data" style="display: none;">Wprowadź poprawne dane</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
if ($('#agents') !== null) {
    $('#label-searchbar').html('Imię, Nazwisko, Adres email');
    $('#input-searchbar').attr('placeholder','Podaj imię, nazwisko lub adres email');
} else if ($('#company') !== null) {
    $('#label-searchbar').html('Nazwa biura');
    $('#input-searchbar').attr('placeholder','Podaj nazwę biura');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property of jQuery object to check an element exists. `$(selector)` will return a jQuery object which never be `null`.

```
if ($('#agents').length > 0) {
    $('#label-searchbar').html('Imię, Nazwisko, Adres email');
    $('#input-searchbar').attr('placeholder','Podaj imię, nazwisko lub adres email');
} else if ($('#company').length > 0) {
    $('#label-searchbar').html('Nazwa biura');
    $('#input-searchbar').attr('placeholder','Podaj nazwę biura');
}
```